# Git push -f origin [branch] isn't working

Tags: git, github

After using `git push -f origin [branch]`, there is still an error while pushing the code in one's own branch of someone else's repo which has been forked.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you post the error that you are getting? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Error: failed to push some refs to [URL]

Comment: Did you add your changes using `git add filepath/filnename.js`. Did you do a `git commit -m "some message"`? what happens when you type `git status`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to push to a forked branch, it means that you will have to create a pull request by committing your code to a branch. Once the Pull Request is created the original author of the repository will be able to then review your pull request aka PR and merge your changes to the original Repository. You can further read about it at [Creating a pull request from a fork](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request-from-a-fork/)

If you can provide more details with the steps to reproduce your issue, we can guide you further.